# Can't figure out this exact differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have been solving a thermodynamics problem where I have two representations:

$(\dfrac{∂v}{∂p})_{θ}$ = $vg(p)e^{-θ}$; $(\dfrac{∂v}{∂θ})_{p}$ = $vp^{2}e^{-θ}$

I want to find $v(p,θ)$, so I am using the fact that $dv$ is an exact differential:

$dv = (\dfrac{∂v}{∂p})_{θ} dp + (\dfrac{∂v}{∂θ})_{p} dθ$;

So $(\dfrac{∂M}{∂θ})_{p} = (\dfrac{∂N}{∂p})_{θ}$, where $M = (\dfrac{∂v}{∂p})_{θ}$ and $N = (\dfrac{∂v}{∂θ})_{p}$

$-vg(p)e^{-θ} = 2vpe^{-θ}$

So for this equality I found $g(p) = -2p$

Substituting I get this expression

$dv(p,θ) = -2vpe^{-θ}dp + vp^{2}e^{-θ}dθ$

But now I'm stuck on this part, cause I dont know how to solve an exact differential equation with two independent variables.

Comment: There are several issues in your work - (1) where did the factor of $v$ disappear to in both partial derivatives? (2) why did $g(p)$ change to $-2p^2$ in the final line?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I already corrected the errors

Comment: Note that you treated $v$ as a constant when you differentiated. Of course it’s not.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial p}&=-2vpe^{-\theta}, \tag{1a}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}&=vp^2e^{-\theta}. \tag{1b}
\end{align}
We first solve $(1\text{a})$ as a conventional ODE, treating $\theta$ as a constant:
$$
(1\text{a})\implies \int\frac{dv}{v}=-e^{-\theta}\int 2p\,dp \implies
\ln |v| = -e^{-\theta}p^2+f(\theta) 
$$
$$
\implies v=\exp\left(-e^{-\theta}p^2+f(\theta)\right). \tag{2}
$$
Now we plug $(2)$ into $(1\text{b})$ and solve the resulting ODE for $f(\theta)$:
$$
\left(e^{-\theta}p^2+f'(\theta)\right)\exp\left(-e^{-\theta}p^2+f(\theta)\right)
=p^2e^{-\theta}\exp\left(-e^{-\theta}p^2+f(\theta)\right)
$$
$$
\implies f'(\theta)=0 \implies f(\theta)=c. \tag{3}
$$
We conclude, therefore, that
$$
v(p,\theta)=C\exp\left(-e^{-\theta}p^2\right). \tag{4}
$$